# How to find the element in this below case while working with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
  <td class="button" align="center">
  <span id="button">
  <a href="javascript:doApply()">
  <span>Apply</span>
  </a>
  </span>
  </td>
```

Hi friends in the above code am unable to find the element i tried using css selector but not helped me

Comment: but the question is which element you want. text Apply, href , button??

Comment: Which element do you try to select?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

Use below Xpath:-

```
//span[contains(.,'Apply')]
```

Hope it will help you :)